# Question example in the tour is misleading

Tags: discussion, tour-page

The [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) page has this [question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower) as an example of, apparently, a good question:

[image]

The full question text:

> Will Swift-based applications work on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)/iOS 7 and
> lower?
>
> For example, I have a machine running OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), and I
> am wondering if an application I write in Swift will run on it.

This question, like many other *old* questions, has gained many views, with many upvotes, and once used to be considered "good" on Stack Overflow.

I'm (very) sure that if this question would be asked today, it'll be closed as "too broad" with comments like "did you try it?".

I think it will be very helpful for newcomers to see a different question (drawn from [this query to reflect the actual conditions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/473660/possible-tour-questions-and-near-misses)), that actually reflects the quality we are looking for.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a question? I fear that you will propose a "debug my code" question, and then I will bang my head repeatedly against the desk.

Comment: I actually think that question isn't *unreasonable* per se. Not the *best example* exactly, but it's hardly "too broad". "Just try it" is hardly an appropriate solution either, since I may not easily have a 10.8 machine at hand.

Comment: @deceze I agree, maybe "just try it" isn't the best comment to drop. I think that "not the *best example*" is a good-enough reason to replace the question in the page we always redirect newcomers to.

Comment: I'll agree with that. It's not *bad* as is, but could certainly be *better*.

Comment: @CodyGray I was actually thinking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java) (not really).

Comment: We have *so many* excellent performance/optimization questions. I actually wouldn't be opposed to picking one of them. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-count-variable-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance) is one of my all-time favorite questions, and it continues to be incredibly useful. Problem is, we need something *short* for the Tour. Large blocks of code won't work.

Comment: The requirements for the question here are [fairly specific](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/1224/51). Moderators should be able to see an "edit question" button though. Perhaps a better question can be selected? Unfortunately that question doesn't seem to be eligible @TinyGiant as it contains too much formatting.

Comment: There are 34 pages of questions to choose from. No promises, but how does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215374/determining-to-which-function-a-pointer-is-pointing-in-c look?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo

Comment: Wow, I am in shock that the person who asked that question didn't get pestered with a ton of comments demanding an MCVE. @undo Anyway, it isn't my favorite question and I'm unconvinced that it's better than the currently chosen one. Maybe you can include that query for the candidate questions in this question?

Comment: May I suggest that we post suggestions as answers (one suggestion per answer) so we can vote on them and structure the comments? And yes, if you could share the query, @Undo, I'd be very grateful as I'm failing to create it myself.

Comment: @5gon12eder I'm using a page shown to moderators for choosing these questions. I don't have a query.

Comment: inb4 comments flooded with link onl... I think I was too late?

Comment: @5gon12eder: Try http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/473660/possible-tour-questions-and-near-misses

Comment: @NathanTuggy Cool thanks a lot for your effort. I'll look into that list tomorrow but I gotta go now. Do you want to edit the question to add the link?

Comment: Maybe [the one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1394393) that inspired a unicorn shaped T-Shirt?

Comment: Guys, why are we looking for an *existing* question? Can't we just mock a good one? :/

Comment: @MarounMaroun If you've got an example of a good question that doesn't already exist, why not just ask it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Can't we just limit the actual list of questions to newer ones? That probably will narrow options, excluding old ones that community would not allow today. No?

Answer (score 5):

It is probably best to just leave it as it is. The criteria (listed below for reference) are very specific, and it will be very difficult—if not impossible—to find a post that fits within that criteria, *and* satisfies everyone's standards.

> - Open and owned by a user (i.e. not anonymous or community wiki)
> - Score >= 5
> - Length <= 400
> - Contains at least two answers with score >= 1 and at least one comment each
> - Questions and answers must not contain any lists, block quotes, code, images, or header formatting in the body
>
> <sup>[How we can change unicorns eating daisies?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1224)</sup>

The major limiting factors being that the length must be less than 400 characters and that the questions and answers must not contain any lists, block quotes, code, images, or header formatting in the body.

---

I had originally suggested the following question, but it turns out that even this question doesn't meet the criteria because the answers have code blocks and other disallowed formatting.

<s>This one is perfect:</s>

> ### [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770/4639281)
>
> How do I convert a `string` into an `integer` in JavaScript?

- It fits within the criteria
- It is "mentally accessible" enough for any new user to understand, so long as they know what a string and an integer are.
- It is short and to the point
- It would not be closed as anything other than "duplicate" if it were asked today

It has been expressed in the comments here that basic questions are very bad and should be downvoted and closed. That premise is completely erroneous. If every basic question on this site was closed and deleted this site would be useless for anyone other than experienced programmers, which is only a portion of the target audience of this site.

Regardless, I'm not going to get into the virtues of not shooting ourselves in our collective foot.

Comment: It's actually very bad question, if asked today. I bet it'll get -10 votes, and can be closed for many reasons.

Comment: How so? It is not too broad, it is not primarily opinion based, it is not unclear, it is a programming question, it is not a debugging question so it doesn't require an MCVE, it is not a typo, in fact it does not fit the closure criteria for anything other than duplicate, because it would be a duplicate of itself. Anyone downvoting such a question, if not a duplicate, should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: Then newcomers might think that "How to add String to int in C" is a valid question as well.

Comment: If it hasn't been asked yet, then it is a valid question

Comment: Not every question that hasn't been asked yet is a good one. The one I suggested lacks minimal research efforts, and doesn't meet the community standards.

Comment: It is a valid question, that is not off-topic in any way. It may not meet your standards but it does meet the community's standards which are set forth by the available close reasons. Sure you may feel like downvoting it, but if it hadn't been asked before then it very well could be useful for future viewers. If we only allowed content that did not exist elsewhere, we would have no content

Comment: Noob questions are fine for SO when there's no obvious way to quickly look up the answer. The JavaScript type system is wonky. It doesn't have a well-known sponsor from which to look up rules, compares to, say [DB/2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009474). So most anything about JavaScript is useful for SO's Q&A. However, it would be better to have a question that gave a hint of how much richer the depth of the SO Q&A typically is, so long as it still makes sense to the uninitiated.

Comment: @Maroun it turns out this question doesn't fit the criteria, even as basic as it is, because the answers contain code blocks. So good luck finding a question that meets your standards *and* fits within the criteria.

Comment: @EdwardBrey as I said in my last comment, good luck finding one that fits the criteria and is what you're looking for.

Comment: lacking research isn't a close reason. A question lacking research or being in general low quality doesn't make it an invalid question, it just makes it a low quality one.

Comment: lol if high rep users who participate in meta can't figure out what a good question is, good luck to the newcomers

Comment: Alright, I'm giving up the search too. There are many promising questions in the query Nathan Tuggy has constructed. But if it is required that *no* answer may contain any of the mentioned markup, then this is almost an impossible mission. (Btw, I don't understand that requirement. I can see that it makes *some* sense for the question and the top answer but *all* answers…)

Comment: Any idea why the prohibition against lists, block quotes, code, etc exists? Alternatively, is there some official reference for this restriction? Or should I just ask a new Meta question about it? The help center's ["how to ask" page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says, "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them..." So why wouldn't we want to highlight that in our *canonical example of a good question*?

Comment: @KyleStrand Because that is not a *"canonical example of a good question"*. It is an example of *a question* used for showing what tags are and such. Obviously they want it to be short and to the point as to not distract from the guided introduction.

Comment: @TinyGiant How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122610/why-does-the-java-api-use-int-instead-of-short-or-byte)?

Comment: @Maroun blockquotes and code blocks in the answers, it doesn't fit the criteria.

Comment: @TinyGiant Good lord. You do realize that using a question to *demonstrate how the site works* implicitly tells new users "this is an example of a *good* question", don't you? No wonder new users are so frequently confused.

Comment: @KyleStrand I figure they were looking at it more from a design standpoint (that what it seems like based on the criteria). They didn't want to clutter the tour, so they wanted a basic straightforward question that is understandable by most people. I don't actually think the current question is a bad one, it could use some work, but it isn't as horrible as everyone is making it out to be.

Comment: I almost think we'd be better off with some made up question about unicorns and such, as then no one would be using it as an example of a good question, but rather realize that it is simply an example of *a* question.

Comment: I think we should take the branch prediction Q&A, compact the code examples down into 25px heights to show that there is code, but due to scrolling it is obfuscated, and use that. It will naturally be too complicated to fully gr0k from the small window, but at least it will let users have a glimpse of the level of technical difficulty that we would like to get back to - or at the very least that we strive towards.

Comment: Showing a codeblock in the example question has another benefit--it shows new users that codeblock formatting is possible. Some do not seem to realize this.

Comment: @KyleStrand The tour is not supposed to show every type of formatting that can exist in a post. That's what the editing reference is for. I'm not advocating for keeping the criteria the way it is, just providing a devil's advocate response.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't really think that negates the benefit, though. And compared to the rest of the provided formatting options, codeblocks are particularly important on SO.

Comment: @KyleStrand I'm not sure if I agree that the tour is the right place to put that, given the aim of the tour. If you introduce too many concepts at once, stuff gets missed. I think that there should be more emphasis put on visiting the help center at the end of the tour.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage the example question has over most of the suggestions in comments is that it requires almost no knowledge of specific platforms or languages. Okay, you might not know what Swift is or what's going on with the specific different OS X versions, but if you know what a programming language is and understand that OSes go through upgrades, you can get the gist. And if you don't know that much, writing a good SO question is probably a lost cause anyway.

Whatever question replaces this one should be approachable by very new programmers, and it certainly shouldn't require a lot of deep level knowledge of a particular technology or language. It should be a basic question that a newcomer can probably get the gist of having only a minimum of programming knowledge. A question that doesn't fall into that category is unlikely to be helpful for a newcomer trying to figure out what makes a good question.

(Yes, I'm aware this makes choosing a new question a lot more difficult.)

Comment: This is why I was suggesting JavaScript questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't think JS is fundamentally more accessible than other languages.

Comment: Well, seeing as every person that has access to a web browser can run a JavaScript program using solely that browser, I'd say it *is* fundamentally more accessible than most other languages, as most other languages require much more than just a web browser

Comment: @TinyGiant Mentally accessible.

Comment: Given the nature of JavaScript in comparison to most other languages, I don't see it being any less mentally accessible than any of those languages (fundamentally). Yeah JavaScript is full of gotchas, but a basic JavaScript question doesn't require mention of any of those things.

Comment: Most languages are similar enough that a basic question would be readable to any programmer. One may only know a few languages yet be able to pick up basic syntax of almost any.

Comment: @aw04 The current example question doesn't even assume you know a programming language. It assumes you basically know what an OS is and that programming languages exist. You can mostly understand it with *no* programming knowledge whatsoever. I'm not sure the bar needs to be *that* low, but keeping it that low may have been intentional by SO staff. Keeping it as low as possible is probably a Good Thing.

Comment: Why does the question need to be "mentally accessible"? The arrows are pointing at the scores. A portion of the text is even cut off, preventing users from reading the entire question or answers. You could put lipsum in there and it would still serve the purpose of demonstrating how SO "works".

Comment: @JDB If lorem ipsum would do, then why are we having a debate about the quality of the question that happens to be there at present? The whole *point* of this meta post is to give users a better actual example of a good question. If they can't understand the question, how can they understand whether it's good or bad, much less get an idea of what kinds of questions are good or bad?

Comment: @jpmc26 - I dunno. I'm not involved in that debate.

Comment: @JDB Are so. You're commenting on it. =p

Comment: @jpmc26 - I've said absolutely nothing about the current question. Personally, I think it's fine, but if we're going to replace it, why is "mental accessibility" a metric?

Comment: @JDB Stating that the existing one does its job is certainly expressing an opinion in the debate about what question should go there. My answer doesn't demand a replacement. It merely calls out that being accessible is necessary for a replacement to meet the desired goal of this meta post: to serve as a good example for readers to follow. As I said above, if they can't understand the question, they certainly can't glean anything about what makes a good question from it.

Comment: Well, I could say that running "Swift" on "Mac OSX" isn't very accessible to my grandmother, at which point you might correctly point out that my grandmother isn't likely to visit SO anyway, at which point I would probably point out that [most SO users have at least a passing familiarity with C-style languages](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology), so a javascript (or other C-like language) question wouldn't be too much of a stretch. However, I'm not convinced that's necessary - lipsum would fill the need in that context. Or the current one.

Comment: @JDB I've addressed every single objection you've raised in my answer. Please read it more closely. If you find certain passages confusing, please feel free to point them out.

Comment: No, you didn't, because I don't buy your statement that "*Whatever question replaces this one should be approachable by very new programmers*"... I want you to explain why that's necessary. Certainly having a bad example is not good for the tour page (because it sets a bad precedent and encourages copycat behavior - tho not convinced that's the case here either), but why does the example question need to be comprehensible? If anything, a super complicated question might be good, because it'll take focus away from the question content and focus it on the voting buttons, etc.

Comment: @JDB "A question that doesn't fall into is unlikely to be helpful for a newcomer trying to figure out what makes a good question." *Directly* from my answer. *Go read it and stop trolling in the comments.*

Comment: Right, but that's not the point of that particular section of the Tour. That part of the tour is highlighting the voting and ranking mechanisms. The next section starts dealing with "what's a good question".

Comment: @JDB Then you're debating the initial meta post, not my answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about displaying some bogus question on the Tour site? Just make up something that is 100% standard-compliant. As **@Edward Brey** points out in his answer, any real question that gets picked can be changed or even removed later. I don't think it's possible to navigate to the question itself from the Tour page and I doubt many newcomers will immediately try to search for this question or users involved in it after seeing it on the Tour page, so I don't see any real disadvantages to this approach.

Comment: If you have an actual good question, why not just ask it? I cannot think of a situation where a valid on-topic question would fit everyone's ideas of what a good short question should be, fit the criteria for this slot, does not already exist, but should not be posted.

Comment: For example, there might be an existing question for which the posted answer contains a code block, but it would be a very good question/answer even without the code. Just remove the code and put it as an example.

Comment: I don't think the system is set up that way.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, one should search for a relatively recent and highly upvoted question that *cannot be easily judged at the first sight* and makes the readers raise some eyebrows.

For example, it could be a question about some language features that look very similar, but work in a different way, resulting in slower/faster execution or different memory usage, etc, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x).

Or, it could be about some clever language design or feature, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3).

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) about computer architecture impacting program execution might also fall into this category.

Comment: None of your examples fit within the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A good question and answer need not be the latest revision. After all, anything we pick might be changed later anyway. Some answers start simple and get better (yet more complex) as people comment. If you want a quick thumbnail, you may want the older, simpler version.

Here's an example of a question that addresses a relatively familiar language on a topic that is fairly simple but not obvious or easy to newbies or particularly easy to research:

[What is the difference between HTML tags `<div>` and `<span>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183532/145173)

This [answer revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/183535/1) would make a good example for the tour.

Answer (score 1):

The list of [most-highly-upvoted questions of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) likely has some good candidates to replace the current example question.

For example, [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript) is a very short, sweet, and easily understood question about JavaScript. I think it's accessible even if you don't know JS.

Comment: The answers contain disallowed formatting, sorry but that example does not fit the criteria. I also went through a few pages of the most upvoted questions and have yet to find anything that fits the criteria.

Comment: Maybe someone should request that said criteria be changed. then we can make the example question a "Debug my code for me" question.

Comment: @KevinB I'm smashing my face against my desk right now because of that comment.

Comment: @TinyGiant Because of the second half i assume? :p

Comment: @KevinB yes, that part.